# Cannot start riak: "Failed to load erlang_js_drv.so"

Tags: macos, riak

I have been trying to get riak running on a macbook, following the [official guide](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/mac-osx/)

I have tried pulling the tarball and also installing from source. The result is the same

here is the output from `riak console`:

```
config is OK
-config /Users/jistone/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/app.2015.02.16.22.22.49.config -args_file /Users/jistone/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/vm.2015.02.16.22.22.49.args -vm_args /Users/jistone/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/vm.2015.02.16.22.22.49.args
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 256; 65536 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
Exec:  /Users/jistone/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/bin/../erts-5.10.3/bin/erlexec -boot /Users/jistone/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/bin/../releases/2.0.4/riak               -config /Users/jistone/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/app.2015.02.16.22.22.49.config -args_file /Users/jistone/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/vm.2015.02.16.22.22.49.args -vm_args /Users/jistone/erlang/rktar/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/vm.2015.02.16.22.22.49.args              -pa /Users/jistone/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/bin/../lib/basho-patches -- console
Root: /Users/jistone/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/bin/..
Erlang R16B02-basho5 (erts-5.10.3) [source] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:64] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]

{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,erlang_js,{{bad_return_value,{error,{load_error,\"Failed to load erlang_js_drv.so\"}}},{erlang_js,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: ./log/erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,erlang_js,{{bad_return_value,{error,{load_error,"Failed to load erlang_js_drv.so"}}},{erlang_js,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

`erlang_js_drv.so` does exist:

```
$ find ./ -name erlang_js_drv.so
.//lib/erlang_js-1.3.0-0-g07467d8/priv/erlang_js_drv.so
```

So I'm not sure what the message is about. How can I debug this further?

Comment: When I download the tar and execute it works fine.  Your error message doesn't specifically say 'not found' it says 'load error'.  The first difference I see between your output and mine is your `ulimit -n` is 256, mine is 1024.  Perhaps try increasing that?

Comment: You may be able to get more detail by running `/Users/jistone/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/bin/../erts-5.10.3/bin/erl -config /Users/jistone/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/data/generated.configs /app.2015.02.16.22.22.49.config -args_file /Users/jistone/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/vm.2015.02.16.22.22.49.args -vm_args /Users/jistone/erlang/rktar/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/data/generated.configs/vm.2015.02.16.22.22.49.args -pa /Users/jistone/riak-2.0.4/rel/riak/bin/../lib/basho-patches`. Then from the shell, run `code:load(erlang_js).`, `application:start(sasl).`,`application:start(erlang_js).`

Comment: I was able to get a homebrew install working after raising the open file limit, but still cannot get the source build running. Failing with same error